# DTAttributedTextCell with clickable link

Tags: html, ios, core-text, dtcoretext

I'm trying to reuse DTAttributedTextCell with clickable link. I could get hold of the attributedstring but I'm not sure how i can get the frame for the text such that I can create a DTLinkButton.

Here's the sample code from the Demoapp:

```
- (void)configureCell:(DTAttributedTextCell *)cell forIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSDictionary *snippet = [_snippets objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSString *title = [snippet objectForKey:@"Title"];
    NSString *description = [snippet objectForKey:@"Description"];

    NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<h3>%@</h3><p><a href='http://apple.com'><font color=\"gray\">%@</font>Test</a></p>", title, description];

    [cell setHTMLString:html];

    cell.attributedTextContextView.shouldDrawImages = YES;
}
```

Any pointers will be awesome.